# array_search doesn't return result if key is 1

Tags: php, arrays, function, search, key

I've got a session array, i store some values in it, i print the values - everything ok. Then i am trying to print the keys. Returns the result when the key is 0,2,3 etc but it won't return if the key is 1 even though it does exist and it does have a value associated.

```
if(isset($_GET['sterge']))
{
    $get=$_GET['sterge'];
    $key=array_search($get, $_SESSION['produse']);
    echo $key; //prints 0 if i set $get for the first element in the array, prints nothing if i set the second element, prints 2 for third element and so on...
}
```

If i am printing the element with the key 1, i get the expected result. So i don't know what/where to look anymore...

L.E.
$_GET['sterge'] comes from the next line (in case it matters)

```
foreach($_SESSION['produse'] as $elm)
    echo $elm."<a href='mousi.php?item=$cod&sterge=$elm'>Sterge</a><br />";
```

...which is written before array_search() is called. So what happens is I press "Sterge" and then if(isset $_GET) executes and I only wanted to print the keys just to see if it actually gets them..
Also var_dump($_SESSION['produse']) prints out exactly what i expected it to print, key 1 actually has a value (the expected value) but for some reason, array_search() tells that the value for key 1 "doesn't have a key"...

**Last Edit:** Everything was caused because of my lack of attention. The specific value had a space at the end thus it wasn't the same with the one passed in the array_search() function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[array_search](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php) Returns the key for needle if it is found in the array, FALSE otherwise. echo $key will print 0 when return value is false...
You can check if there is a key with that name in given array like this:

```
if(array_search($key, $array) !== false){echo $key;}else{echo "Key not found";}
```

Make sure you have you session key set. Also check if your session is properly started with [session_start](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php) at each file where you trying to access $_SESSION array and its variables. Use [var_dump](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php) to debug everything and check if your error reporting is enabled:

If this doesn't help, update your question with more info and try to explain your problem better(add relevant code with var_dump results of variables).

To enable error reporting just add something like `error_reporting(E_ALL);` at the beginning of your php script. Here is an example about specifying different error level reporting:

```
<?php
// Turn off error reporting
error_reporting(0);

// Report runtime errors
error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_WARNING | E_PARSE);

// Report all errors
error_reporting(E_ALL);

// Same as error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("error_reporting", E_ALL);

// Report all errors except E_NOTICE
error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);
?>
```

Comment: Errors reporting is on (nothing shows), session_start is on, array HAS elements and they are "dumped" when var_dump is used, but with all these, in case of key being 1, it returns "Key not found"...

Comment: Can you update your question with result of var_dump($_SESSION['produse']) ?

Comment: Thank you kindly for your time!